# uncaught at generateIDs Error: invalid keyPath

Tags: react-native, redux, immutable.js

I got a weird error randomly while running my code and here is the code. Please comment if more details are needed.

**action.js**

```
export function generateIDs() {
  return ({
    type: GENERATE_IDS
  })
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  fields: {
    task_completion_date: { ...initialDateState },
    sale_id: { ...initialFieldState },
    client_id: { ...initialFieldState }
  },
  progressvalue: 1,
  submitting: false,
  submitted: false,
  valid: false,
  statusText: '',
  saleID: null,
  clientID: null,
  reportID: null,
  reportDate: datestring,
  isLoading: false,
  online: true
});
```

Comment: Try return plain object in action `return { type: GENERATE_IDS }`

Comment: @TuanLuong tried, but no change. Its a random kinda error. Not occurring everytime.